# How to download PolyFrag module for Python?

Tags: python

I am wanting to download PolyFrag (explained here: http://www.nhview.unh.edu/pdf/PolyFrag_UserGuide.pdf) and cannot figure out how to add this module to my Python window or ArcPro database. Wondering if anyone knows what it is called or why this won't add?

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _cannot figure out how to add this module to my Python window or ArcPro database_ and _why this won't add_. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The download is available here:
http://www.nhview.unh.edu/polyfrag.html

PDF of program user-guide:
http://www.nhview.unh.edu/pdf/PolyFrag_UserGuide.pdf

Program ZIP including .py and ArcGIS .tbx:
http://www.nhview.unh.edu/Computer%20Programs/PolyFrag.zip

I just googled polyfrag download.